# How to capture dojox.layout.FloatingPane resize event?

Tags: resize, dojo

When FloatingPane change size, I would like to launch a function.
I think there is something with **resizeHandle** but not know how to do.
I use Dojo 1.8+.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have to define an event handler for the resize handler of your floating pane.

For example:

```
require(["dojo/on"], function() {
    var floatingPaneObj = ...;
    ...
    floatingPaneObj.startup();
    on(floatingPaneObj._resizeHandle, "resize", function(e) {
        // Your event handler
    });
});
```

I also made a working JSFiddle to demonstrate it. http://jsfiddle.net/8azsz/2/